# WPF image alternative source from web

Tags: wpf, image, binding

I have images stored into websevers. I would like to have an alternative path where the images are loaded from if the first server is not available.

Something like:

```
   <Image Source="http://server1/images/image1" 
          AlternativeSource="http://server2/images/image1"/>
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucky for us Image control raises an event when it failed to load an image , so its easy to check if the image loading failed.

One approach you can take is extending the Image control .

```
public class AlternativeImage : Image
{

    private bool _tryAlternativeSource ;

    public string AlternativeSource
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(AlternativeSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AlternativeSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ItemTemplate.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AlternativeSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("AlternativeSource", typeof(string), typeof(AlternativeImage), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public AlternativeImage()
    {
        Initialized += OnInitialized;
    }

    private void OnInitialized(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        _tryAlternativeSource = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(AlternativeSource);

        //Note , ths need to be unregistered 
        ImageFailed += OnImageFailed;
    }

    private void OnImageFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs exceptionRoutedEventArgs)
    {
        if (!_tryAlternativeSource)
            return;

        _tryAlternativeSource = false;

        Source = new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFromString(AlternativeSource) as ImageSource;
    }
}
```

And then use it like this

```
<controls:AlternativeImage Source="http://server1/images/image1" 
      AlternativeSource="https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/p/1/005/07f/0e1/07ab226.jpg"/>
```

Uploaded the full code [Here](https://github.com/kojanabzah/AlternativeImage.Wpf)